# self.__class__.foo vs cls.foo in python('s datetime module)

Tags: python

According to the docstring, `datetime.today` is `same as self.__class__.fromtimestamp(time.time())`. While that all makes sense, I'm curious why it's `self.__class__.fromtimestamp` as opposed to `cls.fromtimestamp`. Is it actually implemented as a regular `classmethod` but they're being extra-explicit in the docstring? Is it because `datetime` is old? Is it a C interop thing?

ETA: sorry for being unclear--`cls` is generally used in place of `self` in classmethods:

```
@classmethod
def foo(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Comment: What is `cls` in your example?

Comment: I guess `cls` should be `self`?

Comment: `cls` is the name typically given to the implicit first argument of a `@classmethod`.

Comment: I guess my original question was unclear. I read that docstring to say -- assuming `datetime` did not ship with `today()`, I could write a `today` method (with the typical `self` as first argument and one other arg), and write `self.__class__.fromtimestamp(other_arg)` to get this behavior. If the documentation had `cls` there, I would either (a.) have the same first question I led with, or (b.) produce a `NameError` writing that code.

Comment: After Python 3.2, `datetime` is written in pure Python and you can read the source for yourself: https://hg.python.org/releasing/3.4/file/8671f89107c8/Lib/datetime.py#l674

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`datetime.today()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2494) is a proper (native C in Python 2, pure Python in Python 3) [class method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2843), so it does not even get passed a `self` to refer to.

It has been like this even since the early days of `_datetimemodule.c` so I have no idea where the  [docstring](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/829b49cbd2e4b1d573470da79ca844b730120f3d/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2845) comes from. The docstring however, seems to have been in place even since the initial commit (at least as far git history reaches) of the module. It was probably meant to be an object method at some point and after the change to a class method the docstring was never updated.

However, as noted, I cannot find any evidence that `today()` was ever not a class method.

Also, the [library docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) ([Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.today)) make no mention of `self`:

> Return the current local date. This is equivalent to `date.fromtimestamp(time.time())`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist "don't worry about it, it's C-town" is, as far as I'm concerned, a perfectly satisfactory answer to this kind of thing :)

Comment: Well, after some digging, even the git log does not give any further information. The docstring was as it is now in the initial commit (where datetime supposedly was pulled in over from the CVS repo) and even back then, `today()` was already a class method.